# Disable scroll in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I need to disable a scroll in my HTML page on Chrome. I write the overflow:hidden so that hide the scroll bar and disable mouse wheel in Firefox and Internet Explorer. It still be possible to scroll in firefox with the click on mouse wheel but I don't care about that.

So the overflow:hidden just hidden the scrollbar in Chrome but we can still scroll with the mouse wheel.

I make a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pAjDg/2/) but it throws some bugs with his own scroll bar so I recommend to you to create this simple html script to try:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
overflow:hidden;
}

div{
height:2000px;
width:1300px;
position: relative;
background-image:linear-gradient(blue, red);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<span>Test</span>
</body>
</html>
```

So how can we disable the scroll in chrome? Just for information I plan to make an Android application that's why Chrome is important to me.

EDIT: Chrome bug on my computer so tests aren't good but if you have an android you can navigate to my page [here](http://bories.gg.free.fr/ftp//testChromeOverflow.html) and you will notice the bug: you can scroll with your finger.

Comment: i checked in chrome and no issues..which version are u using..can u show  a screenshot oof your issue

Comment: Update your version of chrome it works fine

Comment: I have this one Version 28.0.1500.72 m, it seems up to date

Comment: @podelo check the below code...@abertil its working as yneeded rt

Answer (score 1):

If it does not work with `overflow:hidden` alone, just use the window height too:

```
document.getElementById('yourDivId').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

Here´s how to disable scrolling in the Android Chrome Browser:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Of course you can enable it again with `document.removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

**UPDATE**

Image
[image]

HTML

```
<div  id="wrapper">

<div></div>
    </div>
<span>Test</span>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
height:580px;
}

body {
    min-height: 580px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div{
    height:2000px;
    width:1300px;
    position: relative;
    background-image:linear-gradient(blue, red);
}

html {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work and in more it make the scroll bar visible

Comment: change the wrapper and body min-height to 580px

Comment: As I said in jsfiddle it works, but in real browser with a HTML page it doesn't

Comment: I tried on another computer and like you say it works. I don't know why in my pc it doesn't works.

Comment: if its working on another computer and mine..then the issue would be with ur pc.

Comment: can u reduce the height and min-height to a smaller value less than 580px and check...try a 400px